# How to set limit amount of clicks button can be pressed using cookies

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how to set limit of clicks in button using cookies

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**Here`s a simple example**

```
const oldCount = localStorage.getItem('buttonCount');
localStorage.setItem('buttonCount', oldCount + 1);
const newCount = localStorage.getItem('buttonCount');

if(newCount < 3){
//your func
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Limit Clicks Button</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button" class="btn btn-success"> Enter </button>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    localStorage.setItem("limit_click",10)
    localStorage.setItem("count",1)
$("#button").on("click",function(){
    var limit = localStorage.getItem("limit_click");
    let count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));    
    (count>=limit)?alert('opps'):localStorage.setItem("count",parseInt(count)+1);
    

}); 

</script>
```